# Extract specific live data after a word from text files (multiple) into xls spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Datalogger saves temperature data in a specific folder as txt files daily, named Data_logs_0718.txt, Data_logs_0719.txt, etc.

Information in the Datalogger looks like this:

```
2022-07-21 20:14:38----------------------------------------
192.168.0.102 (7000):#STA:000000,826;L:273;TM:220721201448;D:5;T:01;C:13;A01:00000;A02:00000;A03:00000;A04:0.002;A05:0.002;A06:0.002;A07:0.002;A08:0.002;A09:0.002;A10:0.002;A11:31.00;P01:00000000;P02:00000000;P03:00000000;P04:00000000;P20:000000000000;P21:0000000000000;K01:10000000000;O01:0000;9C;#
-->2022-07-21 20:14:53----------------------------------------
192.168.0.102 (7000):#STA:000000,826;L:273;TM:220721201503;D:5;T:01;C:14;A01:00000;A02:00000;A03:00000;A04:0.002;A05:0.002;A06:0.002;A07:0.002;A08:0.002;A09:0.002;A10:0.002;A11:30.93;P01:00000000;P02:00000000;P03:00000000;P04:00000000;P20:000000000000;P21:0000000000000;K01:10000000000;O01:0000;A0;#
```

I need to import live data from the txt files and want to show the Date, Time and Specific Data as below in single excel file:

| Date | Time | A11: Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-21 | 20:14:38 | A11:31.00 |
| 2022-07-21 | 20:14:53 | A11:30.93 |

Please note that everyday datalogger creates new txt files

I want to save every data in a single excel file

Comment: What is the meaning of `-->` in Datalogger?

Comment: A data logger is an electronic device that records data over time or about location either with a built-in instrument or sensor or via external instruments and sensors. Increasingly, but not entirely, they are based on a digital processor, and called digital data loggers.

Comment: Do want to read the files once per day, or periodically throughout the day?